# Shorter form of (a == b && b == c)

Tags: javascript

I want to compare three variables to be all equal. Of course this is **not working**:

```
(a === b === c) // beware: true on (true === false === false)
```

So I used

```
(a === b && b === c)
```

But I am wondering if there is a shorter form (like the first one - but working) in which **every variable is only evaluated once**.

EDIT:

My use case is the following expression:

```
(typeof a === typeof b && typeof b === typeof c)
```

I wanted to avoid to

- evaluate `typeof b` twice
- put `typeof b` into a variable

Comment: you can use if(a && b && c)

Comment: `a === b && b === c` is just 4 chars longer.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel That'd result in `true` if `a` was `1`, `b` was `44` and `c` was `882`. They're not identical.

Comment: In the case of three different variables, the effort of creating something to handle this is hardly worth it. If you had a hundred variables to compare, then maybe. Even then though, you should be using an array.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the variable and double-evaluation? `typeof` has no side effects and it's pretty fast.

Comment: In C / C++ we do something like `if ((d = a) == b && d == c)` if evaluation of `a`, `b` and `c` is expensive and copying isn't. Formally this is defined since `&&` is *sequenced*. This might translate to javascript but it's not my field.

Comment: @Bathsheba - AFAIK this will do just the same in JS. However that still involves an extra variable.

Comment: @Vilx: It is just a question of elegance. I am always trying to find the best way.

Comment: Which is why I predicate on "if copying isn't". You'd need a very good reason to adopt my idea.

Comment: @Bathsheba In the case of javascript it [only seems to make it worse](http://jsperf.com/function-call-vs-inline-code).

Comment: @heinob - in that case, I'd say that the naïve syntax is the most elegant way. It's the most readable, and the performance is going to be the best as well.

Comment: @Vilx - I suspected that but hope dies last...

Comment: I know it offends the sense of elegance that one expression is evaluated twice, but it sometimes happens so, that a solution which seems less elegant at first actually turns out to be the best way after some thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, there isn't. If you really want to though, you can make a helper function:

```
function Test3(a,b,c) { return a === b && b === c; }
```

That would be shorter to type, but there are also drawbacks:

- It's a bit more indirect, so the code would be harder to read.
- It might be slower, since a function lookup and call is necessary. However modern JS engines might have optimizations that negate this. If performance of this operation is paramount, better benchmark to make sure.
- Although every expression would only be evaluated once, they would all be evaluated always.

To fix all these shortcomings, we can write it thus:

```
var b = ExpressionB;
if ( ExpressionA === b && ExpressionC === b ) { ... }
```

However this is pretty verbose and includes a temporary variable (which is unavoidable anyway, because you need to compare `ExpressionB` twice but evaluate only once).

Comment: It's also slower as it'd require a function call.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - Yes, that's true.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Are you sure it's slower ? javascript engines can inline function calls.

Comment: @nos - Well, I'm not up to speed with the latest optimizations in the JS engine world, so maybe it can get compiled/inlined/whatever pretty nicely. If speed is important though, better benchmark.

Comment: @nos [Feel more than free to see for yourself](http://jsperf.com/function-call-vs-inline-code). Function calls are ~10% slower (~510 million vs ~580 million operations per second).

Comment: Fun results. :) IE11 totally sucks, however the only one with noticeable performance difference is my aging Opera 12.17.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare an arbitrary number of items, you could use a function that compares all its arguments..

```
function equal(){
  var length = arguments.length,
      first = arguments[0];

  for(var i = 1;i<length;i++){
    if (arguments[i] !== first){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

and call it `equal(a,b,c)` or `equal(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)`